# Checking for windows events in c#, can't find this 2003 event

Tags: c#, windows, logging, events

I read somewhere (and it is true), that windows logs eventID 2003 when you plug in a USB key, and 2102 when you unplug it. (These events do occur on my machine)

this won't work, I can't figure out why, and where to look (another log ?)

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string query = "*[System/EventID=2003]";
        EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("System", PathType.LogName, query);
        try
        {            
            EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
            for (EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventdetail != null; eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(eventdetail.FormatDescription()); // explore the event
            }
        }
        catch (EventLogNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while reading the event logs");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find any event.
using

```
string query = "*[System/Provider/@Name=\"Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode\"]";
```

I do hav some events, thow not the 2003 I am after

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution : as suspected, the logname was not the right one.
changing "System" to "Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational" solved the problem. The microsoft documentation is once again, a total mess, and ridiculously unclear.